# Rescaling a UITableView for the iPad?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ipad, uiview

Recently, I have begun porting my iPhone app to the iPad and I have a view with a UITableView subview.  Is there any way to rescale the table? The autoresizing masks don't blow up the font and I basically just want a rescaled, crisp, larger version of the table for the iPad. Is there an easy way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could set `cell.textLabel.font` to a bigger one in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

You could up the height of each cell by implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, e.g.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return 123.f;
}
```

Those are the ones I can think of, off hand.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the table's rowHeight in the viewWillAppear.

`self.tableView.rowHeight = 130.0;`

Answer (score 0):

Or use the `UISplitViewController`. The Tableview on the left and show the data, which should be displayed if you click one cell in the right view. ;-)